# Сокращенный Леопольд — Л-д / Лео-д / Л-ьд / Л-льд?

Tags: дефис, аббревиатуры

Как делать дефисные аббревиатуры?

`Леопольд — Л-д / Лео-д / Л-ьд/ Л-льд и т. д.`

`Разжёванный — р-ый / р-й / разж-ый / раз-ый и т. д.`

Answer (score 1):

> **3.** *Индивидуальные сокращения* — употребляются только в тексте одного издания, введенные его автором или издателем и так или иначе расшифрованные в нем (в списке сокращений, внутри текста вслед за самим сокращением или перед ним, и в списке и внутри текста). [**4.1.2**]

Если бы я писала особенный опус, то сделала бы такие особенные сокращения с дефисом.

Леопольд — ***Л-д*** (по аналогии с *д-р* [доктор] и *м-б* [масштаб]), при условии, конечно, что в тексте нет сокращений других похожих имен (Леонид, Леонард, Леонхард, Ленард) или слов (леопард, ледоход, луноход, ломбард, лжекороед).
Ну а вдруг? Чтобы не получилось вот такой ситуации:

> Например, в комментариях к «Письмам» Аполлона Григорьева (М.: Наука, 1999), где вместо его фамилии употребляется сокращение Г., автор и редактор не заметили такого слияния в тексте:
> Е. С. Протопопова... учила музыке их дочь Леониду Яковлевну, бывшую предметом долгой и безнадежной любви Г. Протопопова, многолетняя свидетельница этой драматической истории, стала как бы конфиденткой Г. (с. 387). [**4.2.5**]

Разжёванный — ***р-ый*** (если не сокращаются таким же образом другие похожие слова: разобранный, ржавый, рекордный, рискованный).
Оставляем в конце две буковки — *р-ый кусок, р-ый сухарь, р-ая масса* (как в словаре: [разгневанный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — *р-ая мать, р-ая стихия, р-ые речи*).

[Сокращения](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html) (А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора)
[Сокращение слов и словосочетаний](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/docs?layout=item&id=16_15)  ("Грамота")